# How do I retain my subcolumns when converting from Excel to CSV to JSON for Firebase Database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my raw Excel data:
[image: Raw Data]

Here is my PivotTable to give you an idea of how I would like my JSON structure to be:
[image: PivotTable]

But when I convert from .XLSX to .CSV to .JSON and then load this file into Firebase, here is what my data looks like (from what I can see, a completely different structure to my PivotTable):
[image: Firebase Database]

It looks like it has structured the data according to its row number. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON data. It doesn't store tables, nor rows and columns, nor spreadsheets.

So during your conversion process the data gets converted from the table you have in Excel to the most corresponding JSON structure, which means that each row in your table become a top-level node in the JSON, and then each cell in that row became a property with the column heading as the property name, and the value from the cell as the value of that property.

If there was any code involved in this conversion, you will have to modify the code to generate the structure you want. If you've tried to do that but got stuck, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which we can easily reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).